# Is there a way to know which wares will be dropped after killing a merchant?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I'm playing a huge jerk in Divinity: Original Sin 2, killing pretty much any trader I find. Very clearly, they won't drop all the wares they have for sale, but they definitely drop some of them. Is there a way to know which goods will be dropped before murdering the trader?

Comment: Across 80 hours of this game and countless hours of the first, I have never found a rhyme or reason as to what people drop when they die, whether it's traders or enemies etc. I am fairly sure it's the same as normal looting, it's a random roll every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that it's entirely random, yet skill-books seem to have priority. Also all items that you've sold to the merchant will be dropped as well.

Comment: So could I possibly buy everything he has by trading in my items, then kill him, and get all of my items back?

Comment: Yes, that does seem to be the case.